# Flutter adding text into TextField controller

Tags: flutter, controller, textfield

When i use this code it works correctly, the controller.text is updated.

```
textController.addListener(() {
          setState(() {
            textController.text = analyzeText;
          });
        });
```

But when i try to add end of text, it crash does not give error. Why?

```
textController.addListener(() {
          setState(() {
            textController.text += ' ' + analyzeText;
          });
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried saving the text in a separate variable and then assigning it to the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are creating a never ending loop, possibly creating a memory leak of sorts. You have a listener listening for changes in a controller, and inside that listener you are making a change to that very same controller. So once it starts, it never stops. That is very likely to cause a crash.

Comment: Yes you are right, the reason was listener. I fixed it .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because of `StackOverflowError`. It is thrown, when call stack exceeds due to excessive deep or infinite recursion.

```
  setState(() {
            textController.text += ' ' + analyzeText;
          });
```

The above code continuously changing the values controller which will be going to replace the widget inside `WidgetTree`, as `Flutter` is **immutable** it will create Widget again and again in memory, so with this, you will have the above error.